# Get value of environment variables in for-loop

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I have several environment variables

```
pam_branch
app_branch
worker_branch
```

I use an array to define different projects and I want to get the values of these environment variables by rebuilding them in a for-loop

declare -a project=(pam app worker)

```
for proj in ${project[@]}; do
  branch=${proj}_branch
  echo $branch
done
```

It prints

```
pam_branch
app_branch
worker_branch
```

but I want the *value* of these projects.

I tried using a different syntax such as

```
for proj in ${project[@]}; do
  branch="\$${proj}_branch"
  echo $branch
done
```

but I am stuck and haven't found the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
echo $branch
```

by

```
echo ${!branch}
```

in your first example.

Comment: Thanks! That does it. What does it means?

Comment: It prints the content of variable which is the string included in $branch.

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html.  *"If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), it introduces a level of variable indirection. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself. This is known as indirect expansion."*